How do I find the largest possible layout with the amount of money avaliable?
I have a question from a practice exam and I was wondering how to start this.
Here's the Question:
On a property next to a straight road, the owner is constructing a rectangular paddock. The side next ot the road requires more expensive fencing, this will cost 360 dollars  per metre. The fencing on the other side will cost 60 dollars. Call the side on the road $x$ and the other sides $y$.
The owner has a budget of $11760
Find the layout for the largest possible layout of the paddock with the given budget and the fencing costs. Show all relevant working.
I'm not 100% sure how to get the answer here. I started by making the formula with the values given, this is for cost $11760 = 360x + 180y$. Then I tried to find $x$ and $y$ by making each $x$ and $y$ equal 0, then substituted that into the area formula $A = x \times y$ which got me $2134.2 m^2$. However, this question requires optimisation, So I need a formula that can be differentiated so I can find the minimum and the maximum, how could I do this?

Hint: you don't actually need to differentiate to find the maximum of a parabola...

@RedFive I'm still a bit lost, I'm not sure how then to find the maximum area that the paddock can be, am I on the right track or am I completely off. How would i potentially find the maximum area with the budget that's available?

OK. Writing a solution now.

The fence next to the road has length $x$, this means so does the opposite side. The cost of these two fences is then $360x+60x=420x$.
The other two sides, of length $y$ each cost $60$ so their cost is $60y+60y=120y$.
We now have $11760=420x+120y$
Rearranging this gives $y=98-\frac{7}{2}x$.
$A=x\times y=x\times(98-\frac{7}{2}x)=98x-\frac{7}{2}x^2$
$A=0$ when $x=0$ or $x=28$, so the maximum area will occur when $x=\frac{0+28}{2}=14$.
When $x=14,y=98\times 14-\frac{7}{2}\times 14^2=686$
This gives the area as $14\times686=9604m^2$

thank you so much, this helped a ton, I have some other examples I can try now
